# Deploying React App and WordPress on One CloudFront Distribution with Separate Origins and Behaviors: How-To?

Tags: reactjs, wordpress, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

I'm encountering challenges deploying both a React app and a WordPress site on the same CloudFront Distribution domain name while utilizing different origins and behaviors.

**Here's my setup:**

- I have a static website hosting domain serving a React app from an S3 bucket with a Bucket website endpoint
  e.g

  http://react-example-site-build.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com
- Additionally, I have a WordPress site hosted on another domain.
  e.g

  http://wordpress.example.com

**CloudFront Distribution Origins:**
I've configured the CloudFront distribution with two origins:

1. The S3 static website endpoint: `react-example-site-build.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com`
2. The WordPress domain: `wordpress.example.com`

**Behaviors:**
In the CloudFront distribution settings, I've set up six behaviors:

1. Five behaviors for React app routes origin:

- `/signin`
- `/signup`
- `/user/*`
- `/forget`
- `/resetpassword`

2. One default behavior for the WordPress origin:

- `Default(*)`
- **Additionally**, for any routes not matching the React app routes mentioned above, they will redirect to the WordPress site served from the S3 static endpoint.

**Cache Invalidation:**
To handle updates, I've included the following cache invalidations:

- `/resetpassword`
- `/user/*`
- `/forget`
- `/signin`
- `/*`
- `/signup`

**Issues Faced:**
Despite the configuration, I'm encountering the following issues:

1. **404 Errors:** Initially, I faced 404 errors for React app behaviors `(/signin, /signup, /user/*, /forget, /resetpassword)`. To address this, I added `(index.html)` as both the Index and Error documents in the S3 Static website hosting configuration. Although this resolved the errors, I still observe 404s in the console.
2. **User Page Display Issue:** When navigating to pages under the `/user/*` route, initially, the content appears but quickly disappears after login.

I want to understand if my logic and configuration are correct. If so, why am I encountering these issues? If not, how can I effectively deploy both the React app and WordPress site on the same CloudFront Distribution domain name with distinct origins and behaviors?